# ASP.Net search button example to load GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, binding, events

Using ASP.Net 2.0

I need an example of how to load a GridView after clicking a button on the page.

I am unable to get the events right - with the PostBack in the PageLoad, seems it's not getting it right. I have three textboxes whose contents are passed to a query which is executed and a datatable is returned. But how and in which order?

Thansk, 
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the code that you are using so we can see what mistakes you may be making.  Basically, your steps should look like this:

1. Add event handler to button to call a method
2. Within method, retrieve data from database into a datatable
3. Set the gridview.datasource to the new datatable
4. run gridview.databind to bind the data to the grid

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an overview of the page event lifecycle?  If so, you might check out this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

In summary, the events fire in this order:

- PreInit
- Init
- InitComplete
- PreLoad
- Load
- (Events from your controls, including things like "TextChanged" on a TextBox)
- LoadComplete
- PreRender
- SaveStateComplete
- Render
- Unload

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable DT = new DataTable();
   DT = select_grid_obj.selectallrecord(txtsearchrecord.Text);
   GridView1.DataSource = DT;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```